# Send a notification by Lambda function with AWS Pinpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

I have an iOS app with a backend build by `MobileHub` with `API Gateway`, `Lambda`, and `DynamoDB`.
I noticed that the `SNS` function of `MobileHub` has been replaced by `Pinpoint`, and I would like to create a notification system using this new service.

When a user creates a new post through `API Gateway`, a lambda function will be triggered and I suppose I can send a notification to the subscribers by `Pinpoint`.
But I cannot find any example or reference doc in the official website of `Pinpoint`.

Do you have any resource for this scenario or any idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Depends what you mean by notification, I assume you would like to send a push notification to a particular user (*Pinpoint endpoint*).

Pinpoint stores each device associated with a user as an "endpoint", generally created by the AWS client side analytics library (*e.g. amplify analytics*).

## The client

With the amplify analytics library, I call `updateEndpoint` so I can specify a `userId` that is available to Lambda, as well as the device token and remove `optOut` so user can receive the push notification:

1. **`Address`** - The token generated from user accepting push notification permission (*iOS*)
2. **`optOut`** - `NONE` so they can receive push notifications
3. **`userId`** - unique id for user (*Cognito's sub*)

## Lambda (node.js)

Now you can send a push notification, using the `userId` and the Pinpoint SDK.

#### Example:

```
const sendMessagesParams = {
    ApplicationId: process.env.PINPOINT_APP_ID,
    SendUsersMessageRequest: {
        Users: {
            [receiverUserId]: {}
        },
        MessageConfiguration: {
            APNSMessage: {
                Action: 'OPEN_APP',
                Title: 'Message received',
                SilentPush: false,
                Body: `You have a new message`
            },
            GCMMessage: {
                Action: 'OPEN_APP',
                Title: 'Message received',
                SilentPush: false,
                Body: `You have a new message`
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log('sendMessagesParams', JSON.stringify(sendMessagesParams));

pinpoint.sendUsersMessages(sendMessagesParams, (sendMessagesErr, sendMessagesData) => console.log('push sent')
```

For your particular scenario, I set up a **DynamoDB stream** and **trigger a Lambda** when a record changes within the table. You may need to add the IAM permissions manually once the lambda is created.

**Sources**

- [Full list of pinpoint methods you can use in lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html) (*Node.JS*)
- [Update endpoint using Amplify Analytics](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics#update-endpoint) (*JS*)
- [Dynamodb streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) - trigger a lambda

Comment: How are you instantiating pinpoint? I have followed all the documentation but am being informed that sendUsersMessages is undefined. sendMessages works fine..

Comment: I do specify an API version and the region pinpoint is in:

 `const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint({ apiVersion: '2016-12-01', region: process.env.PINPOINT_REGION });`

The process.env constants are listed in the "Environment variables" section below lambda code

Comment: In your Lambda function, do you need to provide AWS credentials or an IAM role? Simply nothing happens when i try to run the code you listed

Comment: @Attaque depends how you implement, for pinpoint I created a mobiletargeting full access policy, to allow sending of messages, also the stream iam role.

```{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobiletargeting:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling a lot getting a lambda function working, so **please see this answer as an addition to the answer from Dylan w.**

## Client

```
import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification';
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';

PushNotification.onRegister((token) => {

    Analytics.updateEndpoint({
        address: token,
        channelType: 'APNS',
        optOut: 'NONE',
        // Customized userId
        userId: "e236e3ea-bas9-4eae-967e-0eb9bcaca26d" // Example
    })

});
```

## Lambda function

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  var pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();

  const sendMessagesParams = {
    ApplicationId: <YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>, // Find it in Pinpoint->All projects
    SendUsersMessageRequest: {
        Users:{<USER_ID>:{}}, // The same userId as set on the client. This way you can "follow" people if they switch device
        MessageConfiguration:{
          APNSMessage:{
            Action:"OPEN_APP",
            Title:"Message received",
            Body:"You have a new message"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    pinpoint.sendUsersMessages(sendMessagesParams, (sendMessagesErr, sendMessagesData) => {
      if(sendMessagesErr) reject(sendMessagesErr)
      if(sendMessagesData) resolve(sendMessagesData)
    });

  });

};
```

**Note that the call to pinpoint is wrapped in a promise**. Because `pinpoint.sendUserMessages` accepts a callback, the execution is continued (async nature of Node), which will shut down the lambda function and you will get no output from the callback function or receive a notification, without awaiting the function to finish.

Comment: I'm getting an:
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Mon Sep 14 08:44:55 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
Do you know how can be fixed? I believe it's something releated to the apigateway response because the push notifications get sent

Comment: I'm using `pinpoint.sendMessages` and it wasn't working (no errors, nothing). I wrapped it in `return await new Promise(...)` and now the message sends because the function waits for it. Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've got something that perfectly works.
The answer is that you have to use "targetClient" to update endpoint inside "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" function.

```
let client = self.pinpoint!.targetingClient
let profile = client.currentEndpointProfile()
print("EndpointId = \(profile.endpointId)")
profile.user?.userId = <YOUR_CUSTOM_ID>
client.update(profile)
```

## Client Side(XCODE)

Here is my [AppDelegate.swift] looks like:
(Important part is inside "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" function)

```
import UserNotifications
import AWSPinpoint
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var pinpoint: AWSPinpoint?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Instantiate Pinpoint
        let pinpointConfiguration = AWSPinpointConfiguration.defaultPinpointConfiguration(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        // Set debug mode to use APNS sandbox, make sure to toggle for your production app
        pinpointConfiguration.debug = true
        self.pinpoint = AWSPinpoint(configuration: pinpointConfiguration)

        // Present the user with a request to authorize push notifications
        self.registerForPushNotifications()

        return true
    }
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, _ in
                print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
                guard granted else { return }

                // Only get the notification settings if user has granted permissions
                self?.getNotificationSettings()
            }
    }
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Register with Apple Push Notification service
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    func application(_: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: Start")
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
        // Register the device token with Pinpoint as the endpoint for this user
        self.pinpoint!.notificationManager.interceptDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken: deviceToken)

        //set custom userId and update endpoint
        let client = self.pinpoint!.targetingClient
        let profile = client.currentEndpointProfile()
        print("EndpointId = \(profile.endpointId)")
        profile.user?.userId = <YOUR_CUSTOM_ID>
        client.update(profile)
    }
    func application(_: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification:\(userInfo)")
        // Pass this remote notification event to pinpoint SDK to keep track of notifications produced by AWS Pinpoint campaigns.
        self.pinpoint!.notificationManager.interceptDidReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo)
    }
}
```

## Backend (Lambda with Nodejs)

And here is a code to send a notification to specific user.

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint({region: 'us-west-2'});


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    const done = (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('ERROR:', err);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify(err)
            };
            callback(response);
        }else{
            console.log('SUCCESS:', data);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            callback(null, response);
        }
    };
    
    
    let users = {};
    users[<YOUR_CUSTOM_ID>] = {};
    const params = {
        ApplicationId: PINPOINT_PROJECT_ID, 
        SendUsersMessageRequest: {
            Users: users,
            MessageConfiguration: {
                APNSMessage: {
                    Action: 'OPEN_APP',
                    Title: "Hi, I am AWS Pinpoint.",
                    SilentPush: false,
                    Body: "You've got a nice message."
                }
            }
        }
    };
    pinpoint.sendUsersMessages(params, (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            done(err);
        }else{
            done(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Hope those work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible with Amazon Pinpoint. You can find the Javascript SDK documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html).

There are 2 modes of sending with Pinpoint.

1. [Direct send](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html#sendMessages-property) - This is effectively the same as what SNS has traditionally been. You need a device token and you can send directly to your push provider using that token.
2. [Segmentation sends](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/campaigns-segment.html) - This mode is slightly different and assumes that you have loaded all your devices into Pinpoint via the Mobile SDK as part of your app, or via an S3 Import.  The benefit here is that you can segment your devices and send to that segment (e.g. 'Ryans Friends').

So in your Lambda backed API you can choose to either send directly to subscribers (if you have their addresses) or potentially an entire segment of subscribers (if you have loaded your endpoints into Pinpoint).

Comment: Should I store the ARNs in my `DynamoDB` table?  Or `Pinpoint` will help me to manage ARNs. If I want to send a message to Ryans Friends segment. How could I recognize this segment is for Ryan this `Cognito` identity?