# Lambda sending notifications via pinpoint is very unreliable, how do I fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, push-notification, permissions, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to send a GCM notification from an AWS lambda function.
I have two questions:

1. What permissions does the exection role require?
2. Is the behavioud described below the best I can expect from AWS notification, do I need to look at another service?

I've followed info from another question:
[Send a notification by Lambda function with AWS Pinpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274726/send-a-notification-by-lambda-function-with-aws-pinpoint)

My lambda is as follows:

```
async function sendMessage() {
  try {
      const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();
      let users = {};
      users["---"] = {};
      const params = {
          ApplicationId: applicationId, 
          SendUsersMessageRequest: {
              Users: users,
              MessageConfiguration: {
                  'GCMMessage': {
                      Action: 'OPEN_APP',
                      Title: "Lambda User Msg",
                      SilentPush: false,
                      Body: "Lambda User Send Message Test"
                  }
              }
          }
      };
      console.log("Params:", params);
      let rspnData = await pinpoint.sendUsersMessages(params).promise();
      console.log("sendUsersMessages:rspnData:", rspnData);
  } catch (err) {
      console.log("sendMessage error:", err);
  }
}
```

1. Can someone advise as to the minimal permissions required by the execution role of the lambda?

I've currently allowed everything pinpoint related, but would like
to be certain what should actually be allows?

2.
When I test the code from the AWS lambda code console I get the following execution log:

```
2022-02-11T08:57:26.446Z    --- INFO    SendMessage
2022-02-11T08:57:26.466Z    --- INFO    Params: {   ApplicationId: '---', 
SendUsersMessageRequest: {
Users: { '---': {} },
MessageConfiguration: { GCMMessage: [Object] }   } } END RequestId:
```

**There is no output from the sendUserMessage!**

ASIDE: I've increased maximum execution time to 20secs, but this feels wrong!

**Or I get an error of the form:**

```
2022-02-11T09:38:32.721Z    --- INFO    sendMessage error: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:639:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1570:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  path: null,
  host: 'pinpoint.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined,
  time: 2022-02-11T09:38:32.721Z,
  region: 'eu-west-2',
  hostname: 'pinpoint.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true
}
END RequestId: ---
REPORT RequestId: ---   Duration: 173.82 ms Billed Duration: 174 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 83 MB
```

Intermitently in the Cloudwatch log I get the following output:

```
2022-02-11T08:54:11.847Z    --- INFO    sendUsersMessages:rspnData: {
  SendUsersMessageResponse: {
    ApplicationId: '---',
    RequestId: '---',
    Result: { '---': [Object] }
  }
}
```

indicating the notification was actually successfully sent!

On some occasions I get a notification in the app!
Usually very delayed!

If I use the same Id's via aws cli:

aws pinpoint send-users-messages --cli-input-json file://pinpoint-send-users-messages.json

I get a prompt notification, as expected!

**Is this the best I can hope for from AWS send notifications, do I need to look at another
service, or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the lambda has the following role.
I don't know if it will be of any help, but please take a look.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "mobiletargeting:SendUsersMessages",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-west-2:{your aws account id}:apps/{pinpoint project id}/messages"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobiletargeting:GetEndpoint",
                "mobiletargeting:UpdateEndpoint",
                "mobiletargeting:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-west-2:{your aws account id}:apps/{pinpoint project id}/endpoints/*"
        }
    ]
}
```